# how to customize wxApp to implement protocol?

Tags: c++, objective-c, wxwidgets, chromium-embedded

I am currently using both `wxWidgets` and `CEF` framework to build a simple application. While trying to work out a clean quit, I figured out that CEF needs the application to implement `CefAppProtocol` so that certain events can be sent back. Currently my code crashes with an exception `[wxNSApplication isHandlingSendEvent] : unrecognized selector sent to instance 0`. I am assuming this has to do with the `wxApp` default implementation. Query is how do I make sure that my instance/ class of `wxApp` confirms to `CefAppProtocol`?

Comment: are you working out of {non-merged} wxCEF old GSoC branch? If not - you can try to grab it, compile it and see if it solves your crash.

Comment: no. I took the version 3.1.2 release.

Comment: try to grab CEF branch out of git. Maybe it will give you an ide4a of what is wrong...

Answer (score 1):

`wxApp` itself doesn't inherit from `NSApplication`, but you should be able to override `wxApp::OSXCreateAppController()` to create a custom "controller", which is used as a delegate with `[NSApplication sharedApplication]` and thus should allow you to handle unknown selectors.

However, it's the "instance 0" part of the message that looks worrisome to me -- doesn't this mean that something is nil when it shouldn't be?